# How do I extract functions that add more attribute after querying result from Mysql inJavascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

As title, I would like to re-organize my data which I query from Mysql server for my GraphQL client.

```
  resolve: (root, { name }) => {
    const weekday = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

    return findCafeshopByName(name).reduce((record, row, i) => {
      record.openingHours = record.openingHours || { [weekday[0]]: record.openingHour };
      record.openingHours = Object.assign(
        record.openingHours,
        { [weekday[i]]: row.openingHour },
      )

      return record;
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I do two things to my raw result from Mysql:

1. Add a new attribute `openingHours` to my record.
2. Use reduce to mapping data row into weekday (digit).

This works like a charm but is not good for scale. Actually, I am considering move the callback in reduce into another directory for well-management. As a newbie in Javascript, I don't know how to name this directory in Javascript. Or am I just think it in the wrong way?

I developed with Ruby on Rails for a while. And we do have something alike in Rails which is called `decorators` when we need some view-only logics in view-model layer.

thanks.

p.s.
`findCafeshopByName` calls knex querying API.

Comment: So you want to know how to move the callback into another file?

Comment: Exactly I want to know how should I name the file which I move the callback in. And how to name the directory also. I am just wondering there is a convention or not.

Comment: That could be subjective. I would name the file something on the lines of `QueryResultModifiers`, and put all the callbacks like the one you have here inside it.

Comment: sounds good. @MaazSyedAdeeb